# Is there any synonym to "ha"?

Tags: expressions, synonyms, tag-questions, sarcasm, interjections

"ha" can be used in a sarcastic way like this:

> A: When did the first war happen?
>
> B: In 1950.
>
> A: Wrong. It happened in 1914.
>
> B: I know that.
>
> A: That's why you answered it correctly, **ha**?

I thought of "huh" as a synonym to it, but its meaning doesn't indicate that.

I found the following web page, but it appeared to have no synonyms to the above case:

https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/ha

The meaning of "ha" according to *Cambridge dictionary*:

> Used to express satisfaction that something bad has happened to
>   someone who deserved it, or to show that you have succeeded in
>   something.

The meaning of "huh" according to https://www.vidarholen.net/contents/interjections/ :

> Really? - Mild, indifferent surprise

Comment: If "ha" was actually written, you should cite a source. It could be an utterance or an error. As spoken, there is little difference between the two.

Comment: I wrote the dialogue myself to be provided as an example of one of "ha" uses. And although I have previous knowledge about "ha", I defined it according to _Cambridge Dictionary_ in my question description above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a few suggestions

[**right**](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Right)

> A **sarcastic** version of agreeing with someone about an argument.
>
> A: That's why you answered it correctly, **right**?

You can place "right" at the beginning or use "sure" in that same place.

**[sure](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=sure)**

> the quickest way to answer a question when not paying attention that usually doesn't include any thinking what so ever. Also used in a **very sarcastic way**.
>
> A: **Right**, that's why you answered it correctly
>   A: **Sure**, that's why you answered it correctly

You can also use a **[question tag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_question)** to show sarcasm

> It is possible for a positive statement to be followed by a **positive tag** for even more effect (**sarcasm**, anger, **disbelief**, shock, concern) {[source](https://www.learnenglish.de/grammar/tagquestions.html)}
>
> A: That's why you answered it correctly, **did you**?

As pointed by @user3169, **huh** is another option.

> "Huh?" is also frequently used in a **sarcastic** or challenging way. With
>   this usage, the "challenged"  information has very high pitch and both
>   the "challenged" information and "huh?" are stressed:
>
> *He isn't hére, húh?*
>   {[source](http://www.eslcafe.com/grammar/tag_questions05.html)}
>
> A: That's why you answered it correctly, **huh**?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was wondering if these are synonyms for the interjection/expression "ha" or suggestions for the case I have provided since that word doesn't exist?

Comment: @TasneemZh I was answering your question, those are synonyms in the context that you have provided. I was not criticizing the use of "ha". It seems a valid word.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like it should have been *huh*.

> A: That's why you answered it correctly, **huh**?

See [**huh**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/huh):

> **Huh** is used in writing to represent a noise that people make at the end of a question if they want someone to agree with them.